# How do I get my equation to have the form $(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 + (z-c)^2-d = 0$?

Tags: output-formatting, algebraic-manipulation, expression-manipulation

I want *Mathematica* to express the equation $$-11 - 2 x + x^2 - 4 y + y^2 - 6 z + z^2=0$$ in the form $$(x - 1)^2 + (y - 2)^2 + (z - 3)^2 - 25=0$$ How do I tell *Mathematica* to do that?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use custom transformation rules, for example:

```
-11 - 2 x + x^2 - 4 y + y^2 - 6 z + z^2 //. 
   (a : _ : 1)*s_Symbol^2 + (b : _ : 1)*s_ + rest__ :> 
       a (s + b/(2 a))^2 - b^2/(4 a) + rest
```

returns

```
(* -25 + (-1 + x)^2 + (-2 + y)^2 + (-3 + z)^2  *)
```

The above rule does not account for cases where `b` is zero, but those are easy to add too, if needed.

Comment: I want the equation has my form exactly, not $-25 + (-1 + x)^2 + (-2 + y)^2 + (-3 + z)^2$.

Comment: @minthao_2011 Mathematica auto-sorts things (`Plus` is `Orderless`), so you will have a hard time achieving this.

Comment: @minthao_2011 You need `% // PolynomialForm[ #, TraditionalOrder -> True]&`

Comment: @Artes Nice! I wasn't aware of this.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Thanks :)

Comment: @ArtesThank you very much

Comment: Leonid, is there any reason you are using `x:_:1` rather than `x_:1` etc.?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Re: `x_:1` - yes, equivalent. Re: the logic - sorry, no time right now, will do later. This is a basic process of [completing the square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square), nothing more.

Comment: Good enough.  Thanks.

Comment: Very nice. I tried `x^2 + y^2 + 2 (m - 1) x - 4 m y + 5 m^2 + 2 m  //.
 (a : _ : 1)*s_Symbol^2 + (b : _ : 1)*s_ + rest__ :> 
  a (s + b/(2 a))^2 - b^2/(4 a) + rest`, gives `-(1/5) - (-1 + m)^2 - 4 m^2 + 
 5 (1/5 + m)^2 + (-1 + m + x)^2 + (-2 m + y)^2`,How can I get `-1 + 4 m + (-1 + m + x)^2 + (-2 m + y)^2`?

Comment: Is using `a_.` different from `a_:1`?

Comment: @Kuba In general, it is. The first form relegates the default value to the function where you use the pattern, the second one specifies it explicitly.

Answer (score 9):

```
eq = (x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 + (z - c)^2 - d;
sol = SolveAlways[{-11 - 2 x + x^2 - 4 y + y^2 - 6 z + z^2 == eq}, {x, y, z}]
eq /. sol // PolynomialForm[#, TraditionalOrder -> True] &

(* {{d -> 25, a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3}} *)
(* {(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2+(z-3)^2-25} *)


eq = (x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 + (z - c)^2 - d;
Solve[ForAll[{x, y, z}, -11 - 2 x + x^2 - 4 y + y^2 - 6 z + z^2 == eq], {a, b, c, d}]

(*{{a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 25}}*)
```

Comment: Your answer depend on the number 25.

Comment: @minthao_2011   Update complete.

Answer (score 9):

A different route:

```
(* polynomial depression *)
depress[poly_] := depress[poly, First@Variables[poly]]

depress[poly_, x_] /; PolynomialQ[poly, x] := Module[{n = Exponent[poly, x], x0},
        x0 = -Coefficient[poly, x, n - 1]/(n Coefficient[poly, x, n]);
        Normal[Series[poly, {x, x0, n}]]]

tst = -11 - 2 x + x^2 - 4 y + y^2 - 6 z + z^2;

vars = {x, y, z};
{cnst, lin, quad} = MapAt[Diagonal, Normal[CoefficientArrays[tst]], {3}];

cnst + Total[MapThread[depress[#1 FromDigits[{##2}, #1]] &, {vars, quad, lin}]]
   -25 + (-1 + x)^2 + (-2 + y)^2 + (-3 + z)^2
```

Comment: This method does not work with mixed products variables in the polynomial. E.g. Thies Heidecke's second example: x^2 - 4 x y + y^2 + 6 x - 4 (see below).

Comment: It wasn't designed for, and shouldn't work on, polynomials containing a cross-term like `x y`. Conventionally (e.g. applications involving conic sections or quadric surfaces), one would apply something like rotation of axes to remove the cross term before one can do completing the square.

Answer (score 7):

An algebraic one:

```
h = -2 x + x^2 - 4 y + y^2 - 6 z + z^2 == 11;
((# /. {x -> 0, y -> 0, z -> 0}) + h[[2]] == #) &@
 Total[(#2/2/Sqrt@#3 + Sqrt@#3 #4)^2 & @@@ (Join[CoefficientList[h[[1]], #], {#}] & /@ {x, y, z})]

(*
 25 ==(-1 + x)^2 + (-2 + y)^2 + (-3 + z)^2 
*)
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer. The right hand side must be 25. Your answer is 11.

Comment: @minthao_2011 Sorry, I forgot one term, corrected now

Answer (score 6):

What about this:

This is your left-hand-side:

```
expr1 = - 11 - 2 x + x^2 - 4 y + y^2 - 6 z + z^2;

expr2=expr1 /. {x -> X + 1, y -> Y + 2, z -> Z + 3} // Simplify
```

The result is:

```
-25 + X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2
```

Now back to old notations:

```
expr2 /. {X -> x - 1, Y -> y - 2, Z -> z - 3}
```

The result is:

```
-25 + (-1 + x)^2 + (-2 + y)^2 + (-3 + z)^2
```

Answer (score 6):

The operation of completing the square with respect to a specified variable is realized by the function `CompleteTheSquare` in the *Manipulations* set of routines from David Park's add-on [*presentations*](http://home.comcast.net/~djmpark/DrawGraphicsPage.html). In your example:

```
expr = -11 - 2 x + x^2 - 4 y + y^2 - 6 z + z^2; 
<< Presentations`
   CompleteTheSquare[CompleteTheSquare[CompleteTheSquare[expr, x], y], z]
(* -25 + (-1 + x)^2 + (-2 + y)^2 + (-3 + z)^2 *)
```

Comment: You could express the last line neatly with a fold: `Fold[CompleteTheSquare, expr, {x, y, z}]`

Comment: @ThiesHeidecke: Sure, `Fold` simplifies the code. I was merely trying to point out that a user need not write --perhaps ought not to have to write -- his own code for such a common operation as completing the square.

Comment: Where should I get the `Presentations\`` package?

Comment: @murray Dear Murray, on my machine Presentations, stopped working. It either happened with passing to Win.10, or to a previous Mma version two versions ago. I cannot tell exactly. I tried to contact David Park and failed. Evidently, Presentations works for you. Could you please kindly comment on this.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch: What exactly do you mean by "stopped working"?  It's working for me with Mathematica 12.3 under macOS Big Sur 11.6. As I recall, there a few names in the package, e.g. EulerAngle that are shadowed by names now in the Mathematica kernel and I had to modify Presentations so as to change the names to something like DPxxx instead of xxx.

Comment: @murray It happened about a year ago, and I do not remember details now. I think, with passing to Win10 it stopped returning help, and something else also happened that I presently cannot recall.  I need to experiment with it to answer you precisely. I will return to you in a few days, if you agree since I am awfully over-occupied now.

Answer (score 6):

The following routine tries to eliminate the linear terms by [completing the square for arbitrary number of variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/256741/10428):

```
CenterPoly[poly_] := Module[{a, b, c, u, vars},
  vars = Variables[poly];
  {c, b, a} = {#[[1]], #[[2]]/2, (#[[3]] + Transpose[#[[3]]])/2} &@
    Normal@CoefficientArrays[poly, vars];
  u = PseudoInverse[a].b;
  (#\[Transpose].a.#)[[1, 1]] &[{vars + u}\[Transpose]] + c - u.a.u
]
```

In case that the polynomial is not expressable solely in quadratic terms it uses the `PseudoInverse` to get a representation that gets as close to purely quadratic as possible.

```
CenterPoly[-11 - 2 x + x^2 - 4 y + y^2 - 6 z + z^2]
(* (x - 1)^2 + (y - 2)^2 + (z - 3)^2 - 25 *)

CenterPoly[x^2 - 4 x y + y^2 + 6 x - 4]
(* (x - 1)*(x - 2(y - 2) - 1) + (y - 2)*(-2(x - 1) + (y - 2)) - 1 *)
```

Comment: In my opinion, your code becomes clearer when you replace your last line by `(vars+u) . a . (vars+u) + (c-u . a . u)`. Or even by `{vars, u, a, (c-u . a . u)}` if you want to bring out the details of the completion of the square more explicitly.

Answer (score 5):

My way for this is:

```
eq = (x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 + (z - c)^2 + d;
eq == 0 /. Solve[ForAll[{x, y, z}, -11 - 2 x + x^2 - 4 y + y^2 - 6 z + z^2 == eq]] // TraditionalForm

(* {(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2+(z-3)^2-25} *)
```

Comment: This solution is already shown: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20159/1871