# Defining a function that completes the square given a quadratic polynomial expression

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, polynomials

How can I write a function that would complete the square in a quadratic polynomial expression such that, for example,

```
CompleteTheSquare[5 x^2 + 27 x - 5, x]
```

evaluates to

> -(829/20) + 5 (27/10 + x)^2

Comment: I already have a solution that I want to discuss and maybe improve. I will post it in 8+ hours as soon as I am allowed to.

Comment: This is a special case (and therefore a duplicate) of [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20051/how-do-i-get-my-equation-to-have-the-form-x-a2-y-b2-z-c2-d-0/). I am not voting to close right now given your desire to post and discuss your solution.

Comment: There is such a function in the "Presentations" package of David Park http://home.comcast.net/~djmpark/index.html

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I was waiting for OP to post his answer before posting mine. In any event, here's a general routine for performing *polynomial depression* (where completing the square corresponds to the quadratic case):

```
depress[poly_] := depress[poly, First@Variables[poly]]

depress[poly_, x_] /; PolynomialQ[poly, x] := Module[{n = Exponent[poly, x], x0},
        x0 = -Coefficient[poly, x, n - 1]/(n Coefficient[poly, x, n]);
        Normal[Series[poly, {x, x0, n}]]]
```

Examples:

```
depress[5 x^2 + 27 x - 5]
   -(829/20) + 5 (27/10 + x)^2

depress[2 x^3 - 7 x^2 + 19 x - 4]
   319/27 + 65/6 (-(7/6) + x) + 2 (-(7/6) + x)^3
```

Comment: Nice generalization. +1

Comment: It looks like there will be a lot of polynomials out there requiring meds after your pogrom of depression. (+1)

Comment: @rcollyer: the mathematicians talk about polynomial "lifting" too; I suppose that's the proper thing to do afterwards...

Comment: First you depress them, then you lift them. Sounds like a cycle of abuse to me. When will the senseless polynomial abuse stop?!? Before you know it, there will be free radicals roaming about trying to cause havoc!

Answer (score 6):

Here's a quick version that uses the matrix approach to completing the square and works for any dimension. It has a couple of checks to make sure that the input is sane, but could have more.

```
CompleteTheSquare::notquad = "The expression is not quadratic in the variables `1`";
CompleteTheSquare[expr_] := CompleteTheSquare[expr, Variables[expr]]
CompleteTheSquare[expr_, Vars_Symbol] := CompleteTheSquare[expr, {Vars}]
CompleteTheSquare[expr_, Vars : {__Symbol}] := Module[{array, A, B, C, s, vars, sVars},
  vars = Intersection[Vars, Variables[expr]];
  Check[array = CoefficientArrays[expr, vars], Return[expr], CoefficientArrays::poly];
  If[Length[array] != 3, Message[CompleteTheSquare::notquad, vars]; Return[expr]];
  {C, B, A} = array; A = Symmetrize[A];
  s = Simplify[1/2 Inverse[A].B, Trig -> False];
  sVars = Hold /@ (vars + s); A = Map[Hold, A, {2}];
  Expand[A.sVars.sVars] + Simplify[C - s.A.s, Trig -> False] // ReleaseHold
  ]
```

For example:

```
In[]:= CompleteTheSquare[a x^2 + b x + c y^2 + d y, {x, y}]

Out[]= -((a b^2 c^2 + a^2 c d^2)/(4 a^2 c^2)) + a (b/(2 a) + x)^2 + c (d/(2 c) + y)^2
```

Answer (score 5):

There's a `ResourceFunction` for this since 9 Aug 2019:

```
cs = ResourceFunction["CompleteTheSquare"]

cs[5 x^2 + 27 x - 5, x]
(*  -(829/20) + 5 (27/10 + x)^2  *)

cs[5 x^2 + 27 x == 5, x]
(*  -(829/20) + 5 (27/10 + x)^2  *)
```

And, oddly, a helper for `ResourceFunction` that does nearly the same thing:

```
ResourceFunctionHelpers`CompleteSquare[5 x^2 + 27 x - 5, x]
(*  -(829/20) + 5 (27/10 + x)^2  *)

ResourceFunctionHelpers`CompleteSquare[5 x^2 + 27 x == 5, x]
(*  -(829/20) + 5 (27/10 + x)^2 == 0  *)
```

Also, `` AlphaScannerFunctions`CompleteSquare `` does the same thing.

Comment: It is a buried but valuable answer

Comment: What is AlphaScannerFunctions? I've done extencive Google has no idea.

Comment: @Anton It is a package/context that contains some functions. `CompleteSquare` showed up when I searched for it (something like ``? *`*CompleteSquare*``).

Comment: @MichaelE2 gotcha

Comment: @MichaelE2 i see. But, how do I use it? AlphaScannerFunctions`CompleteSquare[5 x^2 + 27 x == 5, x] does nothing (

Comment: @Anton Works for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0Uj1.png -- Maybe it doesn't work in old versions?

Answer (score 3):

```
cts[pol_,var_]:= Module[{a, b, c}, 
                        b (a + var)^2 + c /.
                        Solve[ForAll[var, pol == b (a + var)^2 + c], {a, b, c}]]

cts[5 x^2 + 27 x - 5, x]
(*
{-(829/20) + 5 (27/10 + x)^2}
*)
```

and the general solution is of course:

```
cts[a x^2 + b x + c, x]
(*
{(-b^2 + 4 a c)/(4 a) + a (b/(2 a) + x)^2}
*)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's my take:

```
CompleteTheSquare[a_. x_^2 + b_ x_ + c_, x_] := 
 a (x - (-b/(2 a)))^2 + (c - b^2/(4 a))
```

Note the dot after the `a_`, for cases where `a` is 1.

```
CompleteTheSquare[5 x^2 + 27 x - 5, x]
```

gives

```
-(829/20) + 5 (27/10 + x)^2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can work out the general form of the coefficients but here's one implementation:

```
completeTheSquare[p_, x_] := 
 Module[{a, b, c}, (a ( x + b)^2 + c) /. 
   Solve[Thread[
     CoefficientList[Expand[a ( x + b)^2 + c], x] == 
      CoefficientList[p, x]], {a, b, c}]]

completeTheSquare[12 x^2 + 2 x - 7, x]
(*out*){-(85/12) + 12 (1/12 + x)^2}

completeTheSquare[5 x^2 + 27 x - 5, x]
(*out*){-(829/20) + 5 (27/10 + x)^2}
```

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, the following doesn't reveal how to code completing the square. But if you have David Park's *Presentations* add-on (see http://home.comcast.net/~djmpark/DrawGraphicsPage.html), then you can do:

```
   <<Presentations`

   CompleteTheSquare[2 x^2 - 3 x + 5, x]
(*  31/8 + 2*(-3/4 + x)^2  *)
```

And if you look into the `Manipulations` package within *Presentations*, you'll find the code for Park's `CompleteTheSquare`.

Answer (score 2):

this is my own solution:

```
CompleteTheSquare[e_, x_] := Module[{a, b, c, B, C},
   a (x + B)^2 + C //. {
     a -> Coefficient[e, x, 2], 
     b -> Coefficient[e, x, 1],
     c -> Coefficient[e, x, 0], 
     B -> b/(2 a), 
     C -> c - b^2/(4 a)
   }
 ];
```

Comment: I think it is quite readable. Is there any guru around who could elaborate a bit about the different solutions and whether they are equivalent or where they differ?

Comment: You might want to look into `CoefficientList[]`, which gives all the coefficients in one blow.

Answer (score 2):

Storing the general solution as a rule and applying it to expression. (Rule edited after consultation with @Mr.Wizard.)

```
complete = a_. x_Symbol^2 + b_. x_Symbol + c_. :>
   a (x + b/(2 a))^2 - b^2/(4 a) + c;

Sqrt[5]^2 u^2 + 27 u - 5 /. complete

(* -(829/20) + 5 (27/10 + u)^2 *)
```

Comment: Which doesn't work always ...

Comment: Edited, with a optional pattern `_.` that can be missing from the expression, via @RunnyKine.

Comment: I believe `a`, `b`, and `c` should be localized (`:>`).  Also, shouldn't `x` be a parameter?  Perhaps something like this?:  `complete = a_. #^2 + b_. # + c_. :> a (# + b/(2 a))^2 - b^2/(4 a) + c &;` then: 
`5 x^2 + 27 x - 5 /. complete[x]`

Comment: I agree about `x` -- is it just for the case of an arbitrarily named variable? I don't really know about the rule; I can understand `->` vs. `:>` in a case like `{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 5}} /. {i_, j_} -> {i, RandomReal[]}` but what's the difference here?

Comment: `Rule` does not localize symbols while `RuleDelayed` does.  Using your code as written start with `a = b = c = "Fail";` and you will get `(3 "Fail")/4 + "Fail" (1/2 + x)^2`; change only `->` to `:>` and you get `-(829/20) + 5 (27/10 + x)^2`

Comment: BoLe why not update your answer?  I'd like to vote for it, but not in its present state.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Localization, right. I didn't make it as a pure function though, instead I'm relying on an assumption that only a variable headed `Symbol` will appear in `^2` form. Is there a hole in this logic? Or else: vote me up, please. :)

Comment: You've got my vote. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution.  completeSq calls itself recursively until there is no change.

```
completeSq[a_. x_^2 + b_. x_ + c_: 0] := -(b^2/(4 a)) + 
  a (b/(2 a) + x)^2 + completeSq[c]
completeSq[d_] := d
```

It even works with complex real numbers:

```
In[236]:= completeSq[
 4.1 + z^2 + 2 x + I x^2 + 10 y + -3 x - 12 y^2 + 5.1 z + z^2]

Out[236]= (2.93208 + 0.25 I) + I (I/2 + x)^2 - 12 (-(5/12) + y)^2 + 
 2 (1.275 + z)^2
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is pretty old but I want to add a possible solution that I think is simple and worth sharing:

```
CompleteTheSquare[poly_,x_] := Module[                                          
  {cba = CoefficientList[poly, x]},                                             
  c = cba[[1]];                                                                 
  b = cba[[2]];                                                                 
  a = cba[[3]];                                                                 
  a(x+b/(2a))^2+(c-b^2/(4a))                                                                    
  ]
```

It is a simple implementation of the algorithm for [completing the square](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompletingtheSquare.html).

Comment: You might want to localize `a`, `b`, and `c` in `Module`, too. (One can also assign them values with `{c, b, a} = cba;`, which looks cute.)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions!