# Factoring the square of this polynomial?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation

I have a polynomial $$\frac{b^4}{a^4}-\frac{2 b^2}{a^2}+1$$ and I want to complete the square to get this kind of expression: $$\left(1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}\right)^2.$$

I had try:

```
Simplify[1 - (2 b^2)/a^2 + b^4/a^4] (*(a^2 - b^2)^2/a^4*)
```

and the

`Simplify[1 - (2 b^2)/a^2 + b^4/a^4, ComplexityFunction -> LeafCount]  (*(a^2 - b^2)^2/a^4*)`

It seems that the option `LeafCount` for `ComplexityFunction` doesn't make sense here. However we know that

`(1 - b^2/a^2)^2 // LeafCount  (*12*)`

is Less than that

```
(a^2 - b^2)^2/a^4 // LeafCount (*15*)
```

How can I achieve it? Is it possible to achieve it by Simplify?

Comment: Just for reference, this feels a bit related to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20051/47) question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Defining a function that completes the square given a quadratic polynomial expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23014/defining-a-function-that-completes-the-square-given-a-quadratic-polynomial-expre)

Comment: In particular, using [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23059/29734), do `depressPolynomial[1 - (2 b^2)/a^2 + b^4/a^4 /. b -> Sqrt[c], c] /. c -> b^2` or `depressPolynomial[1 - (2 b^2)/a^2 + b^4/a^4 /. b -> Sqrt[c] a, c] /. 
 c -> b^2/a^2`.

Comment: My interpretation is that the OP explicitly asks *"Is it possible to achieve it by `Simplify`"*, so the question doesn't ask for a function that completes squares, but a way to tell `Simplify` to find the desired form as optimal, by virtue of been minimal by `LeafCount `. Therefore IMO this is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Explanation of the problem

The reason it never reaches the form you want despite of being minimal by [`LeafCount`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LeafCount.html) is that **that form is never tried**, so its `LeafCount` is never measured nor compared. Look at the `attempts` with a fresh kernel (as [`Simplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) is cashed).

So the solution is to find a way for [`Simplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) to explore the form you want using [`TransformationFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformationFunctions.html)  and score it as *optimal* as per your definition `ComplexityFunction -> LeafCount`.

```
{sol, {attempts}} = Reap@Simplify[
   1 - (2 b^2)/a^2 + b^4/a^4
   , ComplexityFunction -> ((Sow[#]; LeafCount[#]) &)
   ];
```

[image]

### Solution requested: Simplify

We use [`TransformationFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformationFunctions.html) to tell [`Simplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) to explore the form you want, and [`ComplexityFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexityFunction.html) to define how these alternatives are scored.

One way is to use the `CompleteSquare` described below

```
Simplify[
 1 - (2 b^2)/a^2 + b^4/a^4
 , TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, CompleteSquare[#, b^2] &}
 , ComplexityFunction -> LeafCount
 ]

(-1 + b^2/a^2)^2
```

[image]

Or based on the [answer by Ulrich Neumann](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/204064/10397), also

```
transf[expr_] := Module[
  {vars, tvar},
  vars = Variables[expr];
  ReplaceAll[
   Simplify@ReplaceAll[expr, vars[[1]] -> vars[[2]]/tvar]
   , tvar -> Divide @@ vars[[{2, 1}]]
   ]
  ]

Simplify[
 1 - (2 b^2)/a^2 + b^4/a^4
 , TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, transf}
 , ComplexityFunction -> LeafCount
 ]
(* (-1 + b^2/a^2)^2 *)
```

### PolynomialForm

The [undocumented](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85814/10397) `PolynomialForm` allows placing the terms in the desired order with the option `TraditionalOrder->True`.

```
PolynomialForm[(-1+b^2/a^2)^2,TraditionalOrder->True]
(* (b^2/a^2-1)^2 *)
```

[image]

or

```
Format[bda] = DisplayForm@FractionBox["b", "a"];

PolynomialForm[
 (-1 + b^2/a^2)^2 /. b -> bda a
 , TraditionalOrder -> True
 ]
```

[image]

### Alternative Solution: CompleteSquare

Other people have suggested way to complete the square. 
You can force that form by

```
CompleteSquare[f_, x_] := Module[
  {a, b, c},
  {c, b, a} = CoefficientList[f, x];
  Assuming[
   Sqrt[a] > 0,
    (FullSimplify[Sqrt[a] x] + 
       FullSimplify[b/(2 Sqrt[a])])^2 + (FullSimplify[(a c - b^2/4)])
   ]]

CompleteSquare[1 - (2 b^2)/a^2 + b^4/a^4, b^2]
(* (-1 + b^2/a^2)^2 *)
```

Comment: So, it means that I should supply a method to simplify that could reach the form, and let the simplify to choose it. It means that I should know some methods previous?

Comment: @shelure21 It seems there are no general method implemented in Mathematica that do reach your form. The methods in all the answers are ad-hoc, tailored for a specific case because there seems to be no general way. So yes, you should know based on your case what operation could achieve the form you want and how to gauge it so that it scores optimally.

Comment: Nice, exactly the answers that I want.

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
Simplify[1 - (2 b^2)/a^2 + b^4/a^4 /. a ->  b/λ] /. λ -> b/a
(*(-1 + b^2/a^2)^2*)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do

```
Factor[1 - (2 b^2)/a^2 + b^4/a^4] // FullSimplify
```

or (as suggested by @Thies Heidecke)

```
FullSimplify[1 - (2 b^2)/a^2 + b^4/a^4]
```

with identical output:
$$\frac{\left(a^2-b^2\right)^2}{a^4}$$

which is close.

Comment: It also works without `Factor` (Mma V12, Windows).