# How to perform formula operation on the equation?

Tags: differential-equations

How to perform formula operation on the equation?

1.How to formulate a formula that contains only one parameter?

```
1/4 m^2 + m + 5
```

How to get:

```
1/4 (m + 2)^2 + 4
```

2.How to formulate a formula that contains two parameter?

```
59 - 4 x + x^2 + 16 y + y^2
```

how to get:

```
(x - 2)^2 + (y + 8)^2 - 9
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first one

```
expr = 1/4* m^2 + m + 5;
ResourceFunction["CompleteSquare"][expr, m]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For the second one, the above ResourceFunction does not work since it only supports one variable. But you can use

```
expr = 59 - 4 x + x^2 + 16 y + y^2;
CompleteTheSquare[expr, {x, y}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Where the above function is in the answer by Simon in this post  [Defining a function that completes the square given a quadratic polynomial expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23014/defining-a-function-that-completes-the-square-given-a-quadratic-polynomial-expre)

Comment: ```expr = 59 - 4 x + x^2 + 16 y + y^2;
CompleteTheSquare[expr, {x, y}]```This code does not calculate the answer

Comment: @csn899 did you first evaluate the code given in the link?? it works for me on V 13.2. As I mentioned, I using code posted in another answer.  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcFjd.png)

Comment: Do I need to be connected to the network to use this function(ResourceFunction)?

Comment: @csn899  Yes. But I think there is also a way to download the function to your PC and use it so that you do not need to be connected all the time. I do not know how myself but others would. That is one thing I do not like about ResourceFunctions and that is why I do not use them myself in my code. If you search this site you might find something. If not, you could always make new question about this issue.