# Does Mathematica have a command that can directly get the center coordinates $(x,y)$ and radius $r$ of a circle?

Tags: equation-solving, geometry

I have an equation of a circle:

```
x^2+y^2+2x-15==0
```

Does *Mathematica* have a command that can directly get the center  coordinates $(x,y)$ and radius $r$?

Comment: you could work with ImplicitRegion and RegionCentroid ...

Comment: @george2079 That's a good one (and `1/(2 Pi) RegionMeasure`); I suggest you post this as an answer.

Comment: Indeed, this is what I need.

Comment: [A related question.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20051)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
c = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + 2 x - 15 < 0, {x, y}];
center = RegionCentroid[c]
radius = Sqrt[Area[c]/Pi]
```

> {-1, 0}
>
> 4

Note this does not verify if the input is actually a circle.

Comment: (+1) I would use `==` instead of `<` so that no matter what's on the left/right side of the equation it'll work (assuming it's a circle, of course).

Comment: @corey979 `RegionCentroid` is much slower with the equality for some reason, it does work though. You need to use `ArcLength` instead of `Area` to get the radius.

Comment: `1/(2 Pi) RegionMeasure@c` then. Just for the record, it's minor details.

Answer (score 8):

No, but you can easily implement your own function:

```
f[formula_] := {{a, b}, r} /. 
  Solve[{-2 a == Coefficient[formula, x], -2 b == Coefficient[formula, y], 
         a^2 + b^2 - r^2 == Last@MonomialList[formula], r > 0}, {a, b, r}][[1]]
```

so that

```
eq = x^2 + y^2 + 2 x - 15;

f[eq]
```

> {{-1, 0}, 4}

Answer (score 7):

Method 1:

```
circleForm = (x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 - r^2;
sol = SolveAlways[x^2 + y^2 + 2 x - 15 == circleForm, {x, y}];
Pick[sol, NonNegative[r /. sol]]
(*  {{a -> -1, b -> 0, r -> 4}}  *)
```

As a function:

```
centerRadius[equation_, {x_, y_}] := Module[{res, a, b, r},
   res = SolveAlways[
     (equation /. Equal -> Subtract) == (x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 - r^2,
     {x, y}];
   (* add check/message if SolveAlways fails, if desired *)
   ({{a, b}, r} /. Pick[res, NonNegative[r /. res]]) /; res =!= {}
   ];

centerRadius[x^2 + y^2 + 2 x - 15 == 0, {x, y}]
(*  {{{-1, 0}, 4}}  *)
```

Method 2:  The gradient vanishes at the center; value of form at center is ±1 times the square of the radius, depending on the sign of the coefficients of the quadratic terms.

```
eqn = x^2 + y^2 + 2 x - 15 == 0;
center = First@Solve[D[eqn, {{x, y}}]]
radius = Sqrt[-(eqn /. Equal -> Subtract /. center)]  (* mult. by -1 * sign(coeff(x^2)) *)
(*
  {x -> -1, y -> 0}
  4
*)
```

Circle check (for checking function arguments, if desired):

```
circleQ[form_, {x_, y_}] := With[{ca = CoefficientArrays[form, {x, y}]},
    TrueQ[Length[ca] == 3] && 
     MatchQ[Normal@ca[[3]], {{a_, 0}, {0, a_}}]
    ];

circleQ[x^2 + y^2 + 2 x - 15, {x, y}]
(*  True  *)
```