# How can I transform the circle $x^2+y^2+a x+b y+c=0$ into $ (x-A)^2+(y-B)^2+C=0$

Tags: equation-solving

I want Mathematica to put the circle given by $x^2+y^2+a x+b y+c=0$ into the standard form $(x-A)^2+(y-B)^2+C=0$, but I haven't been able to.

I tried:

```
Solve[
  CoefficientList[x^2 + y^2 + a x + b y + c = 0, x] == 
  CoefficientList[(x - A)^2 + (y - B)^2 + C = 0, 
  {x, y}]]
```

but it's wrong and I don't understand why.

Comment: Related: [how-do-i-get-my-equation-to-have-the-form-x-a2-y-b2-z-c2-d-0](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20051/how-do-i-get-my-equation-to-have-the-form-x-a2-y-b2-z-c2-d-0)

Comment: `Solve[CoefficientList[x^2+y^2+a x+b y+c-((x-A)^2+(y-B)^2+C),{x,y}]==0,{a,b,c}]`

Comment: `sol = Solve[
  First@SolveAlways[(x - A)^2 + (y - B)^2 + C == 
      x^2 + y^2 + a x + b y + c, {y, x}] /. Rule -> Equal, {A, B, C}] `  and then `(x - A)^2 + (y - B)^2 + C /. First@sol `

Comment: The simplest solution may be: Solve[ForAll[{x, y}, 
  x^2 + y^2 + a x + b y + c == (x - A)^2 + (y - B)^2 + C], {A, B, C}]

Answer (score 2):

**Updated**

```
sol = Solve[
  Thread[CoefficientList[x^2 + y^2 + a x + b y + c, {x, y}] == 
    CoefficientList[(x - A)^2 + (y - B)^2 + C, {x, y}]], {A, B, C}]

(* {{A -> -(a/2), B -> -(b/2), C -> 1/4 (-a^2 - b^2 + 4 c)}} *)

HoldForm[(x - A)^2 + (y - B)^2 + C==0] /. First@sol
% // ReleaseHold
```

**Original**

```
Solve[Thread[
  CoefficientList[x^2 + y^2 + a x + b y + c, {x, y}] == 
   CoefficientList[(x - A)^2 + (y - B)^2 + C, {x, y}]], {a, b, c}]
```

> {{a -> -2 A, b -> -2 B, c -> A^2 + B^2 + C}}

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, but go wrong on the details.

```
rules =
  Solve[
    CoefficientList[x^2 + y^2 + a x + b y + c, {x, y}] == 
    CoefficientList[(x - A)^2 + (y - B)^2 + C, {x, y}], 
    {A, B, C}]
```

> ```
> {{A -> -(a/2), B -> -(b/2), C -> 1/4 (-a^2 - b^2 + 4 c)}}
> ```

To show that this is correct transformation:

```
((x - A)^2 + (y - B)^2 + C == 0 /. rules)[[1]]// Simplify
```

> c + a x + x^2 + b y + y^2 == 0

which is the original equation except that the terms are reordered in the way Mathematica prefers them.

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for `SolveAlways`, but it does not choose from the desired parameters and the extra parameters just the ones desired.  So we use the equivalent `Solve[!Eliminate[!eqns,vars]]` form, but with the `Solve` variables specified.

```
std = r2 + (x - x1)^2 + (y - y1)^2;
Solve[! Eliminate[! (c + a x + x^2 + b y + y^2 == std), {x, y}], {x1, y1, r2}]
std == 0 /. First[%]
(*
  {{x1 -> -(a/2), y1 -> -(b/2), r2 -> 1/4 (-a^2 - b^2 + 4 c)}}
  1/4 (-a^2 - b^2 + 4 c) + (a/2 + x)^2 + (b/2 + y)^2 == 0
*)
```