# How can I get the center and radius of this circle?

Tags: equation-solving, complex

I am able to make Mathematica plot the solution to a complex inequality as the interior or exterior of a circle :

Let $a$ be a positive real constant, and $f(z) = \frac{z+1}{z-1}$. I want to get the equation of the image of the disc $D(a) = \{ z \in \mathbb X:\, \lvert z \rvert \le a\}$ by $f$.

If $a<1$, its also a disc, located in the left half plane :

```
ComplexRegionPlot[Abs[(z + 1)/(z - 1)] <= 0.9, {z, 20}]
```

[image: positive circle image]

If $a > 1$, it's the complementary of a disc, located in the right half plane:

```
ComplexRegionPlot[Abs[(z + 1)/(z - 1)] <= 1.1, {z, 30}]
```

[image: all the plane but the circle]

And if $a=1$, it's the full left half plane, which in a certain sense is also a disc.

How can I get the center and radius of this disc depending on the value of $a$ ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a one-liner for obtaining an implicit Cartesian equation:

```
circ = First[GroebnerBasis[ComplexExpand[Abs[(x + I y + 1)/(x + I y - 1)] == a,
                                         TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}], {x, y, a}]]
   -1 + a^2 - 2 x - 2 a^2 x - x^2 + a^2 x^2 - y^2 + a^2 y^2
```

From here, we can use the technique from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23061):

```
vars = {x, y};
{cnst, lin, quad} = MapAt[Diagonal, Normal[CoefficientArrays[circ, vars]], {3}];
cnst + Total[MapThread[depress[#1 FromDigits[{##2}, #1]] &, {vars, quad, lin}]]
   -1 + a^2 - (1 + a^2)^2/(-1 + a^2) +
   (-1 + a^2) (-((2 + 2 a^2)/(2 (-1 + a^2))) + x)^2 - y^2 + a^2 y^2
```

Manual massaging of this result leads to the form

```
(x + (1 + a^2)/(1 - a^2))^2 + y^2 == (4 a^2)/(1 - a^2)^2
```

which means the result is a circle with center `{(a^2 + 1)/(a^2 - 1), 0}` and radius `Abs[2 a/(1 - a^2)]`.

Comment: This is very good. While running your second code chunk, I got an error: `MapAt: Part {3} of {-1} does not exist.` What can I do about it ?

Comment: I had copied the code wrong; apologies. Please also make sure you copied `depress[]` from the answer I linked to.

Answer (score 6):

For concrete values of `a` this can be done as follows.

```
a=9/10;d = ImplicitRegion[ComplexExpand[Abs[(x + I y + 1)/(x + I y - 1)]] == a, {x, y}];
c = RegionCentroid[d]
```

> `{-(181/19), 0}`

```
r=RegionDistance[d, c]
```

> `180/19`

Comment: The above code also works with decimals, e.g.`a=0.009`.

Comment: If $a>1$, the general formula can be derived through `Table[d = 
    ImplicitRegion[
     ComplexExpand[Abs[(x + I y + 1)/(x + I y - 1)]] == a, {x, y}];
   c = RegionCentroid[d]; RegionDistance[d, c], {a, 2, 9}], a] /. 
 a -> a - 1` which produces $\frac{2 a}{(a-1) (a+1)} $.

Comment: This approach also works for arbitrary Moebius mappings.

Comment: To prove that any Moebius map translates circles into circles it is enough to consider $\frac 1 z$ only. The general case is reduced to that case by division and changes. The Mathematica code `ImplicitRegion[ComplexExpand[Abs[1/(x + I y)]] == a, {x, y}]` results in `ImplicitRegion[1/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] == a, {x, y}]`, confirming the claim.

Answer (score 3):

Something really cool I learned, but I cannot find the reference. Probably from one of the authors of [Indra's Pearls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indra%27s_Pearls_(book))...

There is a one-to-one correspondence between circles and Hermitian matrices of negative determinant. Thus, any circle may be  represented by the Hermitian matrix

$H = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & -p \\ -p^* & |p|^2-r^2   \end{array} \right]$

where the complex number $p$ is the circle centre, and the real number $r$ is the circle radius.

The mapping of an input circle to an output circle is accomplished by $G=(M^{-1})^{T*} \cdot H \cdot M^{-1}$, where $M=\{\{a,b\},\{c,d\}\}$ in the Mobius transform. In component form,

$
G = 
\left[ \begin{array}{cc} d^* & -c^* \\ -b^* & a^*   \end{array} \right] \cdot
\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & -p \\ -p^* & |p|^2-r^2   \end{array} \right] \cdot
\left[ \begin{array}{cc} d & -b \\ -c & a   \end{array} \right]
$

where the superscript $*$ indicates complex conjugation. The result is another Hermitian matrix

$
G = 
\left[ \begin{array}{cc} A & B \\ B^* & C   \end{array} \right] = 
\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & -q \\ -q^* & |q|^2-s^2   \end{array} \right]
$

corresponding to a new circle with centre $q$ and radius $s$.

`MobiusMap` finds the coefficients $\{A,B,C\}$ of the Hermitian matrix $G$, and forms the output circle from them. It  has a special case when $A=0$, resulting in a line $U x+V y+W=0$. Ratios taken to form the output circle are independent of whether or not the mapping has unit determinant.

```
MobiusMap[m_?MatrixQ, Circle[{x_, y_}, r_]] :=
   Block[{v = -x - I y, w = x^2 + y^2 - r^2, a, b, c},
      a = Abs[m[[2, 2]]]^2 + Abs[m[[2, 1]]]^2 w - 
          2 Re[m[[2, 1]] Conjugate[m[[2, 2]]] v];
      b = m[[1, 1]] (Conjugate[m[[2, 2]]] v - Conjugate[m[[2, 1]]] w) + 
          m[[1, 2]] (Conjugate[v*m[[2, 1]]] - Conjugate[m[[2, 2]]]);
      c = Abs[m[[1, 2]]]^2 + Abs[m[[1, 1]]]^2 w - 
          2 Re[m[[1, 1]] Conjugate[m[[1, 2]]] v];
      If[
         Chop[N[a]] == 0.,
         LineUVW[{Re[b], Im[b]}, c/2],
         Circle[-{Re[b], Im[b]}/a, Sqrt[b*Conjugate[b] - a*c]/Abs[a]]]
]
```

Your mapping is $M=\{\{1,1\},\{1,-1\}\}$. The Hermitian matrix corresponding to the mapped circle is $G=\{\{1 - r^2, 1 + r^2\}, \{1 + r^2, 1 - r^2\}\}$. Thus, the centre $q=-\{Re[B],Im[B]\}/A=\frac{r^2+1}{r^2-1}$, and the radius $s=\frac{2r}{Abs[1-r^2]}$.

```
Manipulate[
   Module[{circle, q, s},
      circle = MobiusMap[{{1, 1}, {1, -1}}, Circle[{0, 0}, r]];
      q = circle[[1]];
      s = circle[[2]];
      Graphics[{Thick, PointSize[0.015],
         Circle[{0, 0}, r], Point[{0, 0}],
         Red, circle, Point[q]
         }, GridLines -> Automatic, Frame -> True,
         PlotLabel -> "Centre q: "<>ToString[q]<>"    Radius s: "<>ToString[s]]],
   {{r, 0.9, "Radius r"}, 0., 2., Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: Mobius Mapping]

Comment: +1. Nice. How about higher dimensions?

Comment: @user64494 Sorry, no clue. Do you have a reference about what you envision higher dimensions should produce?

Comment: This is really neat. I wrote something like your `MobiusMap[]` [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1171765).